# Notation question ㄴxㄴ(mirror image) and (mirror image) ㄱxㄱ

Tags: real-analysis

I want to know the notation meaning and if you have example let me know

ㄴxㄴ(mirrorimage) //sory i could  find the proper symbol for right one
(right one is mirror image)

(Mirror imagge) ㄱxㄱ // left one should be mirror image
(left one is mirror image)

this notation using in like

$$x * 1/ㄴxㄴ  \leq  x * 1/x  = 1 $$

Comment: Assuming you meant $\lfloor x\rfloor$ and $\lceil x\rceil$, or the [Floor and Ceiling Functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions) of $x$. Latex commands are (\lfloor, \rfloor, \lceil, \rceil), like \lfloor x\rfloor=$\lfloor x \rfloor$.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Patterns_43 they might be floor and ceiling.

So `$$\frac{x\times1}{\lfloor x\rfloor}\le\frac{x\times1}{x}=1$$` will bring you:
$$\frac{x\times1}{\lfloor x\rfloor}\le\frac{x\times1}{x}=1$$

And `$\lceil x\rceil$` will become $\lceil x\rceil$.